# How to resolves output HDMI-1 not found on LInux Mint 20.2, cannot setup dual screen

Tags: amd-graphics, display-settings

I recently installed Linux Mint on my machine. However, I'm currently facing an issue with setting up a dual-screen configuration. I have connected my second monitor using an HDMI cable, but it is not being detected by the system.

I tried using the command

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto
```

but it returns the following error message:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default warning: output HDMI-1 not found; ignoring.
```

Here are my system specs:

- os: Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon
- kernel: 5.4.0-148-generic
- cpu: AMD Ryzen 3 5300U with Radeon Graphics × 4
- gpu: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164c

I have double-checked the cable connection and made sure the monitor is powered on, but still no luck. I'm eager to utilize the benefits of a dual screen setup, so any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

the xrandr command show me this :

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080     77.00*
```

EDIT: and I add your the output of `inxi -Fxxxrz` someone asked me to show him that on Linux mint official forum.

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-148-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.7 wm: muffin 5.0.2 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 
  Distro: Linux Mint 20.2 Uma base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Laptop 15s-eq2xxx v: N/A 
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: HP model: 887A v: 59.21 serial: <filter> UEFI: AMI v: F.27 
  date: 10/20/2022 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 0.6 Wh condition: 39.8/39.8 Wh (100%) volts: 9.3/11.3 
  model: HP Primary type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 3 5300U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 
  type: MT MCP arch: Zen rev: 1 L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 41522 
  Speed: 1667 MHz min/max: 1400/2600 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 
  1: 1304 2: 1601 3: 1390 4: 1724 5: 1303 6: 3119 7: 1645 8: 1700 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A bus ID: 03:00.0 
  chip ID: 1002:164c 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: ati,fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.2.6 
  compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
  bus ID: 03:00.1 chip ID: 1002:1637 
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.5 
  chip ID: 1022:15e2 
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.6 chip ID: 1022:15e3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-148-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtl8821ce v: v5.5.2.1_35598.20191029 
  port: f000 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:c821 
  IF: wlo1 state: down mac: <filter> 
  IF-ID-1: enx1660cb253e1d state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 19.05 GiB (8.0%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: BC711 HFM256GD3JX013N 
  size: 238.47 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> rev: HPS1 
  scheme: GPT 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 231.49 GiB used: 9.42 GiB (4.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1 
  ID-2: /boot size: 703.1 MiB used: 214.1 MiB (30.5%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
  ID-3: swap-1 size: 976.0 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 57.4 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list 
  1: deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-proprietary.list 
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu.list 
  1: deb https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.5/ubuntu focal main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list 
  1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_19.x focal main
  2: deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_19.x focal main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
  1: deb http://packages.linuxmint.com uma main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main
  2: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
  3: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
  4: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
  6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rocm.list 
  1: deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.4.5 focal main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list 
  1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
Info:
  Processes: 362 Uptime: 3m Memory: 7.17 GiB used: 1.70 GiB (23.7%) 
  Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash 
  v: 5.0.17 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Did you try to connect this monitor to the HDMI port of the primary monitor just to check if it works in a single monitor set-up?

Comment: I cannot just connect my computer to this monitor, the monitor works on other pc, same for HDMI câble, but it looks like Linux mint doesn't recognize the HDMI port

Comment: Ah, it's a laptop. Did it have Windows on it before you installed Mint? If yes, did it work with a secondary monitor then? If it did, you might have a driver problem now when using Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU appears to be [AMD's CPU-integrated mobile APU of the Ryzen 5000 series, codenamed *Lucienne*](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/cores/lucienne).

According to the LKDDdb via linux-hardware.org, it is supported starting from kernel version **5.10.**

https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1002-164c-1028-0a8c (although this refers to a similar APU integrated to a Dell system, and your system appears to be a HP)

Unfortunately, it looks like your current kernel version is too old to properly support it, and your display is running on unaccelerated `efifb` framebuffer display support at the moment. This would be why `inxi` lists the graphics driver as `N/A`. The fact that `xrandr` only detects one output named `default` with no gamma information also supports the same conclusion.

The first kernel of the 5.4.x series was [released 24 November 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_version_history#Releases_5.x.y), and your CPU + APU was introduced 12 January 2021, so your hardware **did not exist yet** at the time of that kernel release - always a sign for trouble regarding Linux driver support.

The 5.10.x kernel series was initially released in December 2020 which is still just before official introduction of your CPU series, but at that point AMD was probably already working with the kernel developers to prepare support for their upcoming chips in advance (as Linux-friendly hardware manufacturers often do).